# Copy to file and transform arrays

Tags: array, redshift, copy

I'm copying data from a Postgres DB on AWS RDS to a Postgres-like DB on AWS Redshift.

Varchar arrays are being exported as `{foo,bar}` but Redshift wants them as `["foo","bar"]`.

Redshift doesn't actually have an array type, instead you store it as varchar and read it as a JSON array with their JSON functions.

```
         json_arrays          | is_valid_json_array
------------------------------+---------------------
 []                           | t
 ["a","b"]                    | t
 ["a",["b",1,["c",2,3,null]]] | t
 {"a":1}                      | f
 a                            | f
 {foo, bar}                   | f
 {"one", "two"}               | f
 [x,y,z]                      | f
 [1,2,]                       | f
```

Is there a way to use `COPY TO` and transform the array style, or to configure Postgres to use another array format?

Comment: I don't fully understand how you do the transfer and thus don't know where the right point of the transformation was, but maybe, somewhere in that process, you can use `array_to_json()` (or `array_to_jsonb()`) (and possibly a cast to `text` or `varchar`) to transform the array to JSON?